# how to move a file up the hierarchy in git?

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to move an index.html file from app/pages/index.html to the root of this directory. I have (mv app/pages/index.html) so far, I'm just not sure what to enter next to point it to the root of this repo. Hopefully I explained that right... Thanks.

[image: Repo Snapshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply do `mv app/pages/index.html .` which works because `.` refers to the current directory. However, you probably want to do `git mv app/pages/index.html .` instead, so that git automatically knows about the new file location.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you, I didn't know about the ".".